# Ломается верстка при масштабе 25-33%

Tags: html, css

Cверстал страницу, всё работает, но когда я меняю масштаб до 25% - 33%, то вёрстка частично ломается, подскажите в чем беда?

В браузере Edge и IE 11 таких проблем нет, а вот Хром, Опера, Мазилла, Яндекс браузеры ломают верстку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.button {
background-color:#ee8129;
padding:10px 86px;
position:relative;
left: 8px;
top: 15px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(238,129,41) 0%, rgb(238,130,51) 100%);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #b3560b, 0px 6px 0px #b3560b;
border-radius: 4px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

```
.button:hover { 
left: 8px;
top: 20px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #b3560b, inset 0px -1px 0px #b3560b;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
background: rgb(238,129,41);
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(300, 0, 0, 0.3));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(300, 0, 0, 0.4));
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(300, 0, 0, 0.3));
```

}

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="button">Enroll Today</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код.

Comment: там css кода на 300 строк, как быть?:)

Comment: Добавьте код того фрагмента, который ломается. Судя по картинке, это код кнопки.

Comment: Ну и пусть ломается. Вот если он у вас при 75-150% бы ломался это было бы плохо. А на 25 нужно забить

Comment: Хотя конкретно тут будет достаточно `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо) перестала ломаться) но все равно полезло сбоку, может дело не в кнопке а в белом блоке, в котором вся инфа

Comment: А почему бы не `text-align: center` вместо горизонтльного padding'а?

Comment: На всякий случай я уточню, что так адаптивность не проверяется.

Answer (score 1):

Как написали выше, используйте либо css:

```
white-space: nowrap
```

для текста кнопки,
либо оберните текст кнопки в тег `<nobr>,`

Происходит это из-за того, что разные браузеры по разному рендерят странички при изменении масштаба. Т.е. 1px при 33% - отобразится либо как 0px, либо как 1px, от этого, может немного гулять верстка, если не предусмотрены зазоры для таких случаев.